# Illegal output or input port connection

Tags: verilog, test-bench

So this is my test bench.

```
module testbench;
wire clk;
reg A, B, C, D;
sequential_module sequential_module(.A(A), .B(B), .C(C), .D(D), .clk(clk));
initial
    begin
        $display("Simulating output for Half Subtractor");
        $monitor($time,,," A=%b B=%b C=%b D=%b clk=%b" , A,B,C,D,clk);
        A=1'b0;C=1'b0;D=1'b0; 
        //#1 A=1'b1;B=1'b0;C=1'b0;D=1'b1; 
        //#1 A=1'b1;B=1'b1;C=1'b1;D=1'b0;
        //#2 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

This is my module

```
module sequential_module(A, B, C, D, clk);
input clk;
output A, B, C, D;
reg A, B, C, D;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   A = B;    //blocking statement 1
   B = A;    //blocking statement 2
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
   C <= D;   //non-blocking statement 1
   D <= C;   //non-blocking statement 2
end

endmodule
```

The code is pretty basic but I still can't resolve this problem.

The error (for all 4 ports) :
"Error (suppressible): (vsim-3053) Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'A'"

Comment: please state your problem

Comment: I am recieving this error "Error (suppressible): (vsim-3053) Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'A'" and same as port B, C, and D repeatedly I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: when i tried it in online compiler your code doesn't throw any error,does your code throw error while running without test bed

Comment: there's no error when you compile it but if you simulate it, it has an error

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set variables that are driven by the output of another module. You cannot do that in Verilog (or SystemVerilog). Also, Verilog [only lets connect outputs to wires](http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg). If you are just experimenting, you can use hierarchical references to do that.

```
module testbench;
wire clk;
wire A, B, C, D;
sequential_module s_m(.A(A), .B(B), .C(C), .D(D), .clk(clk));
initial
    begin
        $display("Simulating output for Half Subtractor");
        $monitor($time,,," A=%b B=%b C=%b D=%b clk=%b" , A,B,C,D,clk);
        s_m.A=1'b0;s_m.C=1'b0;s_m.D=1'b0; 
        //#1 A=1'b1;B=1'b0;C=1'b0;D=1'b1; 
        //#1 A=1'b1;B=1'b1;C=1'b1;D=1'b0;
        //#2 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

But real hardware does not have hierarchical references; everything must be connected through ports. You would have to add another set of 4 inputs, plus another LOAD signal.

```
module sequential_module(output reg A, B, C, D, input wire clk,
                         input wire Ain, Bin, Cin, Din, LOAD);
always @(posedge clk)
if (LOAD) begin
   A = Ain;
   B = Bin;
end else begin
   A = B;    //blocking statement 1
   B = A;    //blocking statement 2
end

always @(posedge clk)
if (LOAD) begin
   C <= Cin;
   D <= Din;
end else begin
   C <= D;   //non-blocking statement 1
   D <= C;   //non-blocking statement 2
end

endmodule
```